# Making CMD run as administrator mode automatically

Tags: windows, windows-vista, command-line, administrator

I like to do a <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+ CMD + <kbd>Enter</kbd> but it doesn't run the command prompt in "administrator mode".

I am aware that I can "right-click" run as admin, however I was wondering is there anyway to make the CMD run automatically in administrator mode? (usually most of the things that I need to do with CMD requires admin access anyway)